# Covariance of predictions made from mgcv::gam

Tags: confidence-interval, gam, mgcv

suppose i use mgcv’s gam to predict with some `newdata` producing two outputs(say g1,g2) . How can ask `gam.predict` to return the covariance of the two predictions?

I would like to compute the confidence interval of f(g1,g2) for some f. Assuming  two predictions follow bivariate normal , i could use the delta theorem to compute the confidence interval.

Or is there an alternative method to compute this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are asking, but if you need to calculate the covariance of any two data sets g1, g2 (independently if they are output of function gam.predict) you can simply use the function cov() after calling gam.predict, i.e., cov(g1,g2).

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)